# Program isn't stopping for user input

Tags: c#

When I run my program it just runs straight through and doesn't allow me to enter user inputs.

Here is my main function

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    valueCalculation(validateX(), validateY(), validateZ());
}
```

And here is my validateX function

```
public static String validateX()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your X value: ");
    string x = null;
    do
    {
        x = Console.ReadLine();

        //do stuff
    }
    while(x != null);

    return x;
}
```

Comment: @DanielA.White what about for a non-console application? service, winform, etc

Comment: this is a do-while loop. it should work for once anyway.

Comment: Your loop is not the problem. What is valueCalculation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The presence of:

```
[STAThread]
```

Suggests that this was once a winforms application, which indeed would return `null` for `Console.ReadLine`. Change it to be a console application. If this is in VS2013, right click on the project name; Properties => Application => Output type.

Comment: @user2007843 no, you should **change the project's output type**. As per the information in the answer above.

Comment: @addy2012 doing that by itself will make no difference whatsoever. The important bit is the project's output-type, which changes a flag in the PE header.

Comment: Given so little code, might be a good idea to start a new project and make it nice and clean.

Comment: And once this change is made, the function will lock up because ReadLine will _never_ return null.

Comment: @david unless using stdio and piping in a file via << - will be null at EOF

Comment: @MarcGravell: True. Yes, I did think of eof but the OP said 'enter user inputs' so I assumed that means interactive. I don't think there is any eof char on the console now, is there?